# how to loop to given time in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

im going to loop my time under for loop, please let me know why to correct this.

```
count=3;
Integer timefirst= 30;
LocalTime actime= 10.30 AM;
LocalTime plustime=actime.plusMinutes(timefirst);;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            //how to use LocalTime  under this loop
        }
```

i actully need result is :

```
10.30 am
11.00 am
11.30 am
```

Comment: I suggest you step away from the code for a minute and describe the problem you are trying to solve. When a user runs this program, what does it do? What will the user see on the screen? What actions can they take? What are the results of those actions? Notice that all of these questions should be answered in terms of what the input and output should be. There is nothing at this level about loops.

Comment: actually i need to loop plustime and result like the below

Comment: Do you want to print the results or store them in a `Collection` or array?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, but i dont know how to make it in format with AM/PM

```
import java.time.LocalTime;

class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    final int count=3;
    LocalTime time= LocalTime.of(10, 30);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.println(time);
        time = time.plusMinutes(30);
    }
  } 
}
```

Output:

```
10:30
11:00
11:30
```

**UPDATE**

You can use DateTimeFormater to display time like you need:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.*;
class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    final int count=10;
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a");
    LocalTime time= LocalTime.parse("10:00 AM", fmt);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.println(fmt.format(time));
        time = time.plusMinutes(30);
    }
  } 
}
```

Output:

```
10:00 AM
10:30 AM
11:00 AM
11:30 AM
12:00 PM
12:30 PM
01:00 PM
01:30 PM
02:00 PM
02:30 PM
```

Comment: If you formatted the output according to the desired one mentioned in the question, this answer would deserve an upvote. Hint: `LocalTime` has a method `format(DateTimeFormatter)`.

Comment: @deHaar oh, I noticed Your comment late, I did it a little differently. But i will try to do it with LocalTime.format(DateTimeFormatter).